# Issue with BigQuery WITH clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use BigQuery's WITH clause as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#with-clause). I'm getting an error when running the following query:

```
WITH subQ1 AS (SELECT "1"),
     subQ2 AS (SELECT "2")
SELECT * FROM subQ1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM subQ2;
```

The thrown error is:

```
Error: Encountered " "WITH" "WITH "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>
```

Anyone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)
Rather than this - you should be good!

BigQuery Legacy SQL does not support WITH

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!